# Sorting into groups of 40

Tags: javascript

I need a program that can take input from a user with data quantities and length (feet and inches or just inches) and group the items into groups of 40.

I originally started trying to accomplish this in Excel, but I'm not sure it can be done.

```
var cutList = [
    { qty: 36, feet: 28, inch: 3 },
    { qty: 6, feet: 27, inch: 8 },
    { qty: 12, feet: 27, inch: 3 },
    { qty: 6, feet: 25, inch: 8 },
    { qty: 16, feet: 25, inch: 3 },
    { qty: 22, feet: 22, inch: 8 },
    { qty: 12, feet: 12, inch: 3 },
];
```

Group 1 would have all 36 from the first item plus 4 from the second.
Group 2 would have the remaining 2 items from the second line plus all 12 from the 3rd, and down the line until 40 is hit again. It's been a while since I've done any programming, but I was hoping I could do something like this in JavaScript and embed it in an HTML file for people to use. Ideally they'd be able to copy and paste the data from an Excel spreadsheet into this.

Comment: please add the wanted output and what you have tried.

Comment: what are the remaining 8? i see remaining 2?

Comment: Your math doesn't seem to add up. It seems like you are ignoring the length of the cuttings, and you just want to split based on quantity, is that correct? If so, wouldn't Group 2 contain the remaining **2** from the second line, plus the 12 from the third line, plus the 6 from the fourth line, and so on?

Comment: Once you have the algorithm you can use a library like [HandsonTable](https://handsontable.com/) to format it [on paste](https://handsontable.com/docs/7.1.0/Hooks.html#event:beforePaste)

Comment: Sorry, Math is off. I had typed out some different numbers and then copied and pasted some I was already working on. I edited the post to fix the math. Yes Group 1 would contain 36 from the first line plus 4 from the second. Group 2 would have the remaining 2 from the second line and keep going down the line. The lengths don't matter. They'll already be presorted just need to sort by groups of 40.

Comment: Here's a Google sheet with each row assigned an appropriate GROUP#, it should work pretty much the same in Excel: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1VB3LZi2qUjAsrS-ooInokNNxrRv-ertIrc7x5BabGok/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: A spreadsheet was my initial thought, but I couldn't make it work. That one is close but the excess over 40 needs to be moved to the next group. No group can have more than 40.

Answer (score 1):

There was an answer posted on Friday that I've been playing with and it seems to work. I don't know if it was deleted or edited but I don't see it now. Here is the code:

```js
var cutList = [ { qty: 36, feet: 28, inch: 3 },
                    { qty: 6, feet: 27, inch: 8 },
                    { qty: 12, feet: 27, inch: 3 },
                    { qty: 6, feet: 25, inch: 8 },
                    { qty: 16, feet: 25, inch: 3 },
                    { qty: 22, feet: 22, inch: 8 },
                    { qty: 12, feet: 12, inch: 3 }],
        limit = 40,
        used = 0,
        result = cutList.reduce((r, { qty, feet, inch }, i) => {
            var rest, min;
            while (qty) {
                if (used === 0) r.push([]);
                min = Math.min(limit - used, qty)
                r[r.length - 1].push({ qty: min, feet, inch, limit });
                qty -= min;
                used += min;
                if (used === limit) used = 0;
            }
            return r;
        }, []);

    console.log(result);
```

So to whoever posted this on Friday, Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

My interpretation of the requirement follows.

### // input:

```
var cutList = [
    { qty: 36, feet: 28, inch: 3 },
    { qty: 6, feet: 27, inch: 8 },
    { qty: 12, feet: 27, inch: 3 },
    { qty: 6, feet: 25, inch: 8 },
    { qty: 16, feet: 25, inch: 3 },
    { qty: 22, feet: 22, inch: 8 },
    { qty: 12, feet: 12, inch: 3 },
]
```

### // proposed output:

```
let manifest = [
  {batchName:A, batch: [{feet: 12, inch: 3}, ... to 40]},
  {batchName:B, batch: [{}, {}, {}, ... to 40]},
  {batchName:C, batch: [{}, {}, {}, ... to 40]}
]
```

If the above datagram accurately reflects what you're looking for then the pseudocode can be completed, as both precursor to writing test cases and the algorithm.

### // pseudo:

```
.get line {cutListItem}, sequentially
.set {runningTotal}
.write new {batchName} to {manifest}
do while 
.test {cutListItemQty} !== 0
.enumerate decremeent (--) {cutListItemQty} from {cutListItem}
while {runnintTotal} + {qty} in {cutListItem} <= {batchSizeLimit}
do .write to {manifest} 
do until either condition:
  {cutListItemQty} from {custListItem} === 0
    .read {cutList} .get next {cutListItem}
  {runningTotal} === {batchSizeLimit}
    .init {runningTotal}
    .loopback new {batchName}
```

### // considerations

With the sequential method, A chief benefit is being able to stop at any time to then add or change entries which have not yet been processed. Generally, sequential processing offers better overall workflow integration, too, being able to fit asynchronously into a larger process involving the flow of data from creation through various mutations of use. Potential loss is minimized to what remains of the generated list and its progenitor cutlist entries.

At the level of final processing `{qty}` would be aggregated into `batch`, and dropped from the datagram, but you might want a reference to the `ids` of the originating cutlist entries contained in each batch. That speaks to your `cutlist`, outlining the potential need for identifiers on each entry. We're simply mapping rows and columns here... So, to extend the datagram layout, I'm wondering how you'd view, say, another array entry for each batch, something like: `{originsList: [id#3, id#1, id#...], ...}`?

I've learned a lot here, so I feel you're in the right place to discover how to put together a working model of your data for a site. And given the programming language internal data type match to your cutlist, from a technical perspective, you appear to be on the right track.

**Edit:**
The following doesn't hold a candle to what is an artfully concise and complete answer provided by Nina Scholz. Reading her elegant submission again, and comparing it to the original question, I learned my understanding of the problem was limited, as she deeply dives into a min/max solution.

She sets the bar high, and it is a pleasure to read her work. I will continue to learn from that depth of insight as my practical knowledge of Javascript matures in terms of control flow and data structures.

In any case, my code follows:

```js
let cutList = [
    { qty: 36, feet: 28, inch: 3 },
    { qty: 6, feet: 27, inch: 8 },
    { qty: 12, feet: 27, inch: 3 },
    { qty: 6, feet: 25, inch: 8 },
    { qty: 16, feet: 25, inch: 3 },
    { qty: 22, feet: 22, inch: 8 },
    { qty: 12, feet: 12, inch: 3 },
]
// add id field to cutlist retaining this in the array for check against final manifest entries
cutList.filter((item) => item.qty !== 0).forEach((item, idx) => {item.id = idx + 1})

// could expand objects in number of qty to this or new array, keeping original array entries
// Or, decrement the item.qty as each new replica is made with item.subId as an identifier

let qtyTotal = 0
let pooled = []
// console.log(cutList)
// expand cutlist entries by qty to new array, pooled, adding subId to each entry
let arrays = cutList.map((item, idx) => {
    // forEach works here, probably better, too - lots of bloatiness going on in either case, trails of replicated lists, not a good production solution
    // aggregate entry qty for a total as each entry(item) is parsed
    qtyTotal += item.qty
    for (let i = 0; i < item.qty; i++) {
        let o = {}
        o = Object.assign(o, item)
        o.subId = i
        o.id - i
        // console.log(o) // console.dir(o) would be better
        pooled.push(o)
    }
    return pooled
})

// the list manifest will be chunked from
// console.dir(pooled)
// console.log('arrays.length: ', arrays.length)

// make sure the sum of qty matches the number
let valid
if (qtyTotal === pooled.length) {
    valid = true
} else {
    valid = false
}
console.log(`qty total: ${qtyTotal} pooled total: ${pooled.length}
The manifest data is ${valid ? 'ready.' : 'not ready for use.' }`)

// no exit, program continues
console.log("Producing manifest...")

// chunk pool by batchsize
let chunkedList = []
function produceManifest(start, batchsize) {
    let i = start
    let k = 0
   do {
        let qty, feet, inch, id, subId
        let x = []
        let j = 0
        do { 
            // assign objects from the pool into batchsized arrays
            // console.dir(pooled[i]);
            // if (typeof pooled[i] === undefined) break;
            try {
                ({qty, feet, inch, id, subId} = pooled[i])
                i ++
            } catch(e) {
                // console.error(e)
                // break
            }
            x[j] = {qty, feet, inch, id, subId}
            // console.log(x[j])
            j ++
            if (i >= pooled.length) break;
            // console.log("getting j: " + j)
        } while (j <= batchsize - 1) // index in reference array starts at 0
        chunkedList[k] = [...x]
        // chunkedList.push[x]
        // console.dir(chunkedList)
        k ++
    } while (i <= pooled.length - 1)
    // console.dir(chunkedList)
    return chunkedList
}

// manifest is an array containing batches of the number requested
// do the job
let start = 0
let batchsize = 40
let printable = produceManifest(start, batchsize)

console.dir(printable)

console.log('debug')
```

Comment: i am not sure about your proposed output. can you add some more possible values to it?

Comment: ```manifest = [{originIds: [1, 2, 3], batchName:n+1, batch: [{feet: 12, inch: 3}, {feet: 12, inch: 3}, {feet: 12, inch: 3}, ... to 40]}, ...n+1].``` This was in two parts in my original answer. So, it's a manifest of batches, each manifest entry containing 40 pairs having ```feet, inches```. ```qty``` is pivoted from the original to ```originIds``` in the ```manifest```. Cutlist entries determining start and end points break in the middle of ```qty```. So ```originIds```  may contain the same ```id``` in two adjacent ```manifest``` entries, last and first, respectively, in the sequence read.

Comment: Can you still see the answer from Nina Scholz? I don't see it on this page anymore. I had copied it on Friday.

Comment: All I see is your repost of her Master answer... I'd hate to think she felt I'd polluted the stream with derivative and decided on that basis to leave. She may have been able to provide a bridge between my hashing it out to compressing the parts into an efficient form, like the intricate clockwork she presented. I'm sorry to see her go. I'm glad you kept the code. Now I have a copy to study as I tune up from something more basic along those lines. I like how it doesn't make copies of copies, but filters down to a final output with what's given. Tickles the mind, for sure.